# Take a photo and saving the photo to storage fails

Tags: flutter

I am using the [camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) to take a picture like this:

```
image = await cameraController.takePicture()
```

It is working great and I can display this image in a preview. Now I want to store the picture to the device, and I am trying this:

```
Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path;
String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/images/${image!.name}';
await File(image!.path).copy(filePath);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/data/user/0/dk.hempelfonden.frontier/app_flutter/images/CAP8310428751941012175.jpg', path = '/data/user/0/dk.hempelfonden.frontier/cache/CAP8310428751941012175.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to copy the image file to a directory that was not existing, added this code:

```
String dirPath = '$appDocumentsPath/images';
await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

path is the directory /data/user/0/dk.some.app/cache/CAP7304644252296628120.jpg. Try adding a /filename.jpg or .png to it.

```
Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path;
String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/images/$name.png';
logDebug('Saving from: ${_image!.path}');
logDebug('Copy to: $filePath');
return await File(_image!.path).copy(filePath+".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to copy .png file to .jgp path that is why you are facing
**FileSystemException** try same image type for both image paths.

Comment: Nice spottet, changed the code but same error

Answer (score 0):

you have not created the file. so thats why its show you error

```
File newFile = File(await filePath);
   
if (newFile.existsSync()) {
  await newFile.delete(); // Delete File first
}
newFile.createSync(recursive: true); // Create Again
```